# Byte numbering question

Tags: c++

In this byte formula

```
y=(((x[0]<<8)+x[1])*1);
```

would `x[0]` refer to the left most byte or the right most byte?

Lets say in Hex the number x was `10DF`, what would the result be?

Comment: That depends on the endianness (byte order) of the system. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness for more info.

Comment: This is a bit easier on the eyes, Mike: `y=(x[0]<<8)+x[1];`

Comment: you'll have to rephrase your question a bit, see the discussions in the answers, it is really not clear what is it that you're asking here.

Comment: I think I get it now. I was thinking that the first part (x[0]<<8) would leave me with 0000 0000. This I would add to x[1] 1101 1111 for a result of 1101 1111. I see now I think that the first part   (x[0]<<8) gives me 0010 0000 0000 0000 which I add to x[1] 1101 1111 for a result of 0010 0000 1101 1111. So x and y both equal 10DF

Answer (score 2):

`x[0]` refers to the leftmost byte in the number, i.e. the one closer to the beginning of the address space.

If those two bytes contain the number 0x10DF, `x[0]` is 0xDF if the system is little endian and 0x10 if the system is big endian. If we assume that bit of code is just trying to extract the number from memory, I'd imagine that the number in memory is big endian because it's left-shifting (multiplying) the first byte, meaning it's more significant.

Comment: @Matti, I'm not sure you're right.  `0x10 << 8` will give `0x1000` regardless of endianness, so in this case `x[0]` will always be the most significant byte, regardless of the storage.

Comment: @littleadv: The last part was just my educated guess as to which endianness the number in memory may have used - big endian makes more sense here because if it was little endian it would end up swapping its bytes (which may or may not be desirable). Could you be a bit more specific as to what I'm wrong about?

Comment: @Matti - about `x[0]` being `0xDF` of course. If `y` is `0x10DF` then `x[0]` must be `0x10`.

Comment: @littleadv: I guess I interpreted the question differently then. I thought `x` contained the number 0x10DF, and `y` was just an arbitrary result variable. Obviously if the result is the same, then the system has to be big endian.

Comment: Hi guys! This was my first post here and I want to thank you all very much. I did not expect this many replies.

Comment: The formula is supposed to give me a result that is meaningful from the byte value of 0x10DF. I'm not 100% certain but I believe Y = 0x10DF also. C++ isn't what I normally code in and I'm not really 100% sure the formula is C++. I don't understand how shifting the bytes gives me a usable number either way. I figured my quickest way to understanding was to determine which byte is which.

Answer (score 1):

`<<` is **shift *left* operator**, so obviously `x[0]` is moving left here. It would be the `0x10` of `0x10DF`.

**edit**

To clarify - I assume that `0x10DF` is the value of the result - `y`.

Comment: Not true... x[0] can be either 0x10 or 0xDF depeding on the endianness of the system.

Comment: @Sani, it looks like the number is stored in MSB order, which suggest big endian.

Comment: @littleadv: how do you determine that the order is big endian? The usage of the left-shift operator does not inheritly say it is so. It might still be little endian. However it is a STRONG reason to conclude the system is big endian but not conclusive.

Comment: @Sani, just because of the order in the array - `x[0]` is the MSB and comes first. But, it is irrelevant, the endianness has nothing to do with the question. As I pointed in my other comment, `0x10 << 8` will yield `0x1000` regardless of the endianness. In this case, `x[0]` is the most significant byte, and endianess of the system has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @littleadv: ofcourse endianness is significant here. The number the OP is referring to is 0x10DF. He doesn't say the bytes stored are 0x10 in x[0] and 0xDF in x[1]. If the number is stored as a WORD on a little endian system then the BYTE x[0] would be 0xDF.

Comment: @Sani, I think we have a confusion here:-) I'm assuming that `0x10DF` is the value of `y`. Otherwise the question doesn't make much sense (at least to me).

Comment: @littleadv: "Lets say in Hex the number was 10DF, what would the result be?" This means, to me atleast, the number is 0x10DF where x[0] is either 0x10 or 0xDF and the OP wants to know what the result (y) will be of the computation. Since we don't know the endianness (with absolute certainty) we can give him/her both answers. But better yet teach him/her about endianness and let him/her learn for him/herself.

Comment: @Sani and @littleadv: Thank You for your help. If it helps you with the endianness the decimal conversion of 0x10DF would be 4,319.

Comment: @Mike - endianness influences the way the value is represented in the memory. 0x10DF is 4319, regardless of endianness, it's just the same value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that x was a multi-byte value, the `leftness' of x (or more precisely its *significance*) is dependent on the endianness of whatever architecture you are using:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

On x86, the higher address byte is the more significant value.

EDIT: Thanks to Rob for spotting the typo earlier

Comment: X86 is little-endian; the lowest address holds the least significant byte.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy:  ack!  You are right.  I mistyped in my hurry to mash the submit button :P

Answer (score 1):

Endianness is not immediately an issue, because no pointer casting is involved. Suppose we have:

```
unsigned char x[] = { 0xAB, 0xEF };
```

Then the following algebraic expression is completely portable and representation-independent:

```
unsigned int y = (x[0] << 8) + x[1]
```

The result will always be `y == 0xABEF`. (Let's assume that we have `CHAR_BITS == 8`.)

It is an entirely different matter how this is layed out in memory, which *does* depend on the machine endianness. This information is accessible through type punning:

```
uint16_t z = *(uint16_t*)(x);
```

Now in *memory* `z` is layed out as `AB EF`, whatever that means: 0xABEF on big- and 0xEFAB on little-endian systems.